# How can I rotate multiple objects at a time on Draw.io (relative, not absolute rotation)?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Alright, so I'm creating a card game, and there's an icon and number on the top left of the card. On the bottom right, it should be mirrored so that if the card is dealt upside-down, time is not wasted. A good example is standard playing cards with the numbers and royals mirrored on both sides.

My icon consists of multiple shapes in different rotations (20,5,350,335 degrees), so it would be tedious to manually rotate. Example: https://gyazo.com/1951f9bf82435518fe19a070d54b5ae6

When I try to rotate all of them, there is no button for relative rotation -- I can only enter an absolute rotation such as 90 degrees in the format panel, and then my icon is messed up.

For now, I ended up manually rotating all of them and changing the coordinates so that the manual rotations would fit as a whole. Maybe I might be wasting my time, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ABSOLUT ROTATION:**

- hold **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** key and select objects you want to rotate
- go to **Arrange**
- select **Direction**
- select **Rotation**
- enter the desired value
- press **Apply**

> [image]

---

**RELATIVE ROTATION:**

- hold **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** key and select objects you want to rotate
- press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>G</kbd>** to lock them in a group
- rotate object as desired

---

**RELATIVE ROTATION TO OUTSIDE POINT:**

- hold **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** key and select objects you want to rotate
- press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>G</kbd>** to lock them in a group
- go to **Arrange**
- select **Direction**
- select **Rotation**
- enter the desired value
- press **Apply**
- rotate object as desired based on outside point

Comment: Actually, this just does absolute rotation, not relative rotation.

Comment: @CreativiTimothy I see, answer updated...

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I found it out eventually for relative rotation. You need to group the objects first.

- Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key and select the objects to group.
- Click **Arrange -> Group**, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>
- Proceed to rotate as you would with one object, as the grouped objects are now considered one object (but you can un-group them).